# Efficient way to edit a list of EF entities

Tags: c#, algorithm, entity-framework

I would like to know your opinion about an efficient way to update an entity that contains a collection of child-entities, using EF. I am not very familiar with the inner workings of EF.

Let's say we have a Study entity, that has many Center entities. The two tables are linked using a linking table that contains only IdStudy and IdCenter.
The list of centers that belong to a study can easily change. Every study has between 1 and 50 centers.

For example: the initial selection was center 1,2,3,4. The user edits the list by removing 1,2 and adding 5,6. So the new list would be 3,4,5,6.

What approach would be more efficient to update the DB?

1. Delete all existing entries. Inserting all items in the new list.
2. Determine what is new. Determine what should be inserted. Delete what is no longer selected. Insert new.
3. For each item in the new list, update the existing records. Delete the remaining records if new list has fewer elements. Insert the rest of the elements if the new list has more.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you asking about the code efficiency, or the DB efficiency? If you're using EF, you don't have to worry about what will happen in the database: you manage your list properly, and EF will handle deleting/inserting/updating based on how the latest model from the DB compares to the model that you're giving it to save. I'd guess it would choose option 2.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I always go with the first option. Writing code that updates everything if necessary, and deletes the right records afterwards, is just too cumbersome.

You can delete all pretty quickly with Entity Framework, and you can all do it in a transaction even. So I'd go with the first option. It's less code, easier to read and easier to maintain.

Of course, if you want to keep an audit trail (what used to be the selected centers before they were edited?), this method is not feasible, or you'll have to think of some other way to implement the audit trail.

And yes, if the list grows quite large (let's say 50 records), then it does become slower to insert 50 rows. Nonwithstanding, your code is far less likely to contain any bugs as it is quite simple. Delete all centers for this Study. Insert new Centers for this study. It's a time-saver as well.

So in short: if performance isn't absolutely critical, spend the extra milliseconds performing the insert operations on your database, instead of writing code that will only update/insert the changed records.

Comment: If "efficient" means *less code* I agree. If it means *better performance*, then depending on the size of your list, option 1 is slower than only *inserting new* and *removing old*. Also option 1 isn't great if you have a type of audit trail.

Comment: You're most certainly right. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The way I prefer is to add few flag properties.

Lets say, you have an EF entity:

```
class Center{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, we create DTO object (to avoid some kind of unwanted editing) as follows:

```
class CenterDTO{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //flag properties
    public bool IsDeleted {get; set;}
    public bool IsUpdated {get; set;}
    public bool IsAdded {get; set;}
}
```

Now, after adding/updating/deleting object we know if it was edited, deleted or updated, thus we can take appropriate approach on each entity.

BTW. For this approach, it is wise to use AutoMapper (Google it, saves a lot of work)

http://automapper.org/